# Ruby on Rails - Store information from frequent API calls in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, single-page-application

I am trying to write a web application in Rails that will basically make frequent API calls (limited to 500 per 10 minutes, will want to be using all of them), store information from the API calls into a database, and process the information to create statistical data for display.

I am thinking of doing this as a single page application, but the only backend stuff I've ever written has been in Rails. Is there a different backend I could be using instead? If I wanted to do it in Rails, how would I go about setting up such a frequent script to run?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [cron](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby) to call a rake task or call a url on the rails application. Or use a scheduling queue like [sidekiq](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq).